# Add text in border of a chip Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I need to create this style with a Chip component pre build with MaterialUI

with html and css the solution will be using  Some Text

but even there the result will not be the same, I saw some example achieving the same with material but using a TextField with an adornment of the Chip but it's not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use the `<Chip>` component, you could use `&::before` on the Chip styling.

Eg:

```
const Chip = styled(MuiChip)(({ chipTitle }) => ({
  "&::before": {
    content: `"${chipTitle}"`,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "-8px",
    left: "16px",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: "0 8px"
  }
}));
```

And use it as:

```
<Chip
  label="Salary Proposal - 500k$"
  variant="outlined"
  onDelete={handleDelete}
  chipTitle="Hello"
/>
```

Check out [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-firefly-wlqssr?file=/src/App.js:551-690). Of course, there might be some difference in terms of personal styling, but update it as necessary.

**If you are using Typescript:**
You need to first create the type that extends the default `ChipProps`.
eg:

```
import {styled, Chip as MuiChip, ChipProps as MuiChipProps} from '@mui/material'

interface ChipProps extends MuiChipProps {
    chipTitle: string
}
```

Afterwards, modify the `styled()` as follows:

```
const Chip = styled(MuiChip)<ChipProps>(({ chipTitle }) => ({
  "&::before": {
    content: `"${chipTitle}"`,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "-8px",
    left: "16px",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: "0 8px"
  }
}));
```

Comment: great! that it's exactly what I was search for

Comment: one question, when I use this in a project with typescript its print  me this.     Property 'chipTitle' does not exist on type '{ avatar?: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | undefined; children?: null | undefined; classes?: Partial<ChipClasses> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "outlined" | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...> & { ...; }'.ts(2339)

Comment: I've updated my answer for TS also.